# Output ImageMagick Result as Base64 String Instead of File

Tags: imagemagick

On the command line, I can do:

```
convert sourceimg.jpg | base64
```

and receive a string of output representing the image.
However, if I add any transformations to the image, nothing is output:

```
convert sourceimage.jpg -resize 400x400 output.img | base64
```

Is there a quick way to get the base64 representation of the result of imagemagick commands?

Answer (score 9):

If you want the output image as a `PNG`, use:

```
convert input.jpg -resize 400x400 PNG:- | base64
```

If you want the output image as a `JPG`, use:

```
convert input.jpg -resize 400x400 JPG:- | base64
```

Comment: From memory there is a limit on the file size when working with base64; I had problems last year but can not remember if it was reading or writing.

Comment: @Bonzo Ok, thanks for sharing your insights. The problem that the OP has here is, I think, that all his output is in the file `output.img` so there is nothing to pass into `base64`. He just needs to omit `output.img` and tell IM to write on `stdout`.

Answer (score 6):

In ImageMagick there is an INLINE: format that will save to base 64. See http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/files/#inline

So you can also do

```
variable=$(convert input.jpg -resize 400x400 INLINE:PNG:-)
```

Comment: This does not work with `convert 7.0.8-14`. A file named `INLINE/PNG/-` is generated. The linked documentation mentions nothing about writing out, only reading in : `Inline images let you read an image defined in a special base64 encoding.`

Comment: It works fine for me on IM 7.0.8.15 Q16 Mac OSX. `variable=$(magick lena.jpg -resize 400x400 INLINE:PNG:-)`. Note in IM 7, use magick not convert. What is your platform/OS? The documentation seems to be lacking about  writing to base64, but it does work as I described.

Comment: I just checked and it does fail for me on IM 7.0.8.14, but works in IM 7.0.8.15. So if on IM 7.0.8.14, try Mark Setchell's solution below.

Comment: MacOS 10.13.6, brew installed imagemagick on 2018-10-29 and lists no updates available. Would you suggest an alternative way to install?

Comment: If you are on High Sierra, then you can install from ImageMagick binary at https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php#macosx. Alternately, what I do is to install all my delegates from MacPorts, then install ImageMagick from source. See https://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=29100

Comment: Mark Setchell's solution below works fine for me on IM 7.0.8.14. `variable=$(magick lena.jpg -resize 400x400 PNG:- | base64)`. Then `echo "$variable" shows the base64 text data.

Comment: IM 7.0.8-15 works @fwm42 thank you! I'll submit the change to homebrew when I can.